# HTML5 Offline Data Storage Options

Tags: sql-server, html, local-storage, offline-storage

A developer buddy of mine just recently started at a new company and one of his tasks is to come up with a new web application that allows their users to work offline when their staff are onsite in remote locations and then later to sync with a server side database of which they have not yet determined a server side provider yet (i'm guessing it will be SQL Server).

I've done some looking around and it seems like two viable options are LocalStorage and IndexedDb, with LocalStorage being the more popular technology? They want to go HTML5 and that's all fine and dandy, but long story short my question(s) is/are...

- What are their offline data storage options in HTML5?
- Are there older solutions that have better support?

  - are those methods less risky?
  - less time to implement?

The concept of storing data offline in a web application doesn't seem like a new idea, but doing so in today's newest technologies (html5, asp.net 4.0/4.5) is where you start getting into sparsely explored territory.

- what are some things that maybe your company does that works, and what doesn't work?

Any intelligent evidence based replies will more than likely get my upvote so don't just rush to get the first answer and try to score some quick points, I'm looking for some good solid feedback here. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several possibilities of offline storage in HTML5:
    Web Storage
    Web SQL Database
    IndexedDB
    Filesystem API

You have a very good presentation of all these options here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/whats-offline/#toc-older-storage

Compared to older options (Cookies, Plugin Based Storage, Browser-specific features) , I'll quote from the article:

"The newer storage APIs, what we might call "HTML5 storage", are generally superior in terms of openness and standards compliance. Of course, not all browsers include all of the new APIs, and you may have to support older browsers that don't include any of them at all. So the older techniques are still useful for graceful degradation."

Other useful links:

http://php-html.net/tutorials/html5-local-storage-guide/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

I think your best choice is using Local Storage since its the most widely implemented standard of the storage options available under HTML5.

IndexedDB has been over-engineered (in my opinion) and is not widely supported (yet) for all of Mozilla's insistence that [its better than sliced bread](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/beyond-html5-database-apis-and-the-road-to-indexeddb/), and WebSQL's future is looking a bit uncertain as Mozilla [is refusing to implement it](http://blog.mozilla.com/standards/2010/04/30/mozilla-at-w3c-review-of-web-applications-wg-charter/) and it is [no longer being worked](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) on due to an impasse between W3C and the browser vendors who have actually implemented it (Chrome/Safari/Opera).

There is currently a bit of a browser explosion happening thanks to smartphone adoption, so its hard to determine how much of the market supports HTML5 LocalStorage features but using [statcounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201010-201110) I've been able to calculate that between Chrome (4+), Firefox (3.+), Safari (4+), Opera (10.5+) and IE (8+), including iPhone and Android devices you'll have captured around 80-85% of the market, with this figure going upwards a rate of 1-2% per month. The remainder being IE 6/7 (which stubbornly tends to hang on), older versions of new browsers (with update features that generally kept them current), and some mobile browsers stuck back in the stone age.

As for older options, I would add [User Data Persistence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531424%28VS.85%29.aspx) for IE6/7 to the list provided by @user998692 but either way you're going to be caught up with lots of browser incompatiblity issues and support for a hodge-podge of technologies, which will complicate your codebase and testing and increase your delivery timelines (and cost) accordingly. If you do want to go down this road, however, I would recommend you take a look at [PersistJS](http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557) as the guys who put it together have done much of the work you would need to already.

These days its worth more looking forward (to what the market will look like in 1-2 years time when your app is propagating and gaining a wide user base) than backwards, so I'd say HTML5 LocalStorage is probably your best option.

Comment: Great Post, and I definitely agree with your last paragraph!

Comment: Love that you said "IndexedDB has been over-engineered". But note that localStorage has 2.5 MB limit. Regarding wrapper library, my favoriate is my own one http://dev.yathit.com/api-reference/ydn-db/storage.html, of course. :-)